# Get Month, Year or Day from a Date and Time Field in Jira for a Filter Query

Tags: filter, jira, jql

I'm trying to make a filter in Jira like this:

```
issueType = MyIssueType ORDER BY YearOfDate(dueDateAndTime), MonthOfDate(duDateAndTime), DayOfDate(duDateAndTime), priority, dueDateAndTime
```

This would order all the tasks by the day of year, then priority, then by the actual time of day of the due date.

`dueDateAndTime` is a "custom field" of type "date and time" where you can pick the day and the exact hour of day.

Is there a way to extract the day, year or month from that kind of field?

Comment: 1. this dont work for you? `issuetype = MyIssueType ORDER BY dueDateAndTime ASC, priority asc` 2. why you like to order after priority again after dueDateAndTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQL doesn't provide a possibility to extract specific parts from a *datetime*.

Does `issuetype = MyIssueType ORDER BY dueDateAndTime ASC` not work?

It would be possible in SQL, There is a plugin for that:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.kintosot.jira.jdbc4jql/server/overview

You would use regular SQL syntax:

```
 SELECT * FROM ISSUES GROUP BY YEAR(dueDateAndTime), MONTH(dueDateAndTime), DAY(dueDateAndTime);
```

Hope it helps.